# SonicWall VPN tunnel is up, but no traffic allowed. Where to begin troubleshooting?

Tags: networking, encryption, vpn, subnet

I'm have a tunnel between a SonicWall NSA2400 (corp office) and a TZ215W (branch). The VPN link shows to be up, however, traffic counter stays at 0 and I can't ping to the remote network.

It's a site-to-site setup:
-corp office:
--IKE preshare
--IPSec gateways set to 0.0.0.0 (dynamic IP at branch)
--local IKE ID: ~WAN IP~
--Peer ID: ~peer's firewall ID~
--Local net: LAN subnets
--Remote net: 192.168.0.0 - 255.255.0.0
--Phase1: IKEv2 > Group2 > AES-256 > SHA1
--Phase2: ESP > AES-256 > SHA1
--NetBIOS bcast enabled

-branch
--IKE preshare
--IPSec gateways set to ~corp WAN IP~
--local IKE ID: ~firewall ID~
--Peer ID: ~corp WAN IP~
--Local net: LAN subnets
--Remote net: 192.168.0.0 - 255.255.0.0
--Phase1: IKEv2 > Group2 > AES-256 > SHA1
--Phase2: ESP > AES-256 > SHA1
--NetBIOS bcast enabled
--Keep alive enabled

The connection status is as follows

```
Name    Local                           Remote                          Gateway
corp    192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255   192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255   ~corp VPN Static IP~
```

Any obvious pieces I'm missing?

Comment: changed locations in the Networks tab to Local 10.100.0.0 - 255.255.0.0 Remote 192.168.0.0 - 255.255.0.0
....
now seing outgoing (branch to corp) traffic but not incoming

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [network engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: My apologies. In any case, I ended up solving the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the "obvious piece" I was missing was the fact that I had 192.168.0.0 for both local and remote LANs. I ended up using 192.168.0.0 for the corp site and 10.100.0.0 for the branch, now all is well.

I've been informed by Mike Pennington that this question is off topic, so it was probably not seen by the intended audience. My apologies for posting, but I suppose writing out the problem helped me see the solution, so thanks anyway!